# Exif image properties not getting not server

Tags: php, imagemagick, exif

I'm using `ImageMagick` to display image details in `zf2` project.

It is displaying all image properties on my local Ubuntu machine. But EXIF image properties are not displayed on the live RedHat server.

Is it due to some wrong server config or PHP config?

I'm using the following code:

```
if (is_file(SHARED_PATH . $fileURL)) {
    /* Create the object */
    $im = new \Imagick(SHARED_PATH . $fileURL);

    /* Get the EXIF information */
    $fileDetails = $im->getImageProperties();

    /* Loop trough the EXIF properties */
    /* foreach ($fileDetails as $name => $property)
    {
        echo "{$name} => {$property}<br />\n";
    } */
    $fileType = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype(SHARED_PATH . $fileURL));
    $fileSize = number_format($im->getImageSize() / (1024 * 1024), 2) . 'MB';
}
```

Comment: It may be the case that it doesn't work on both systems equally well or at all, because your versions are different... So first of all: please state clearly the ***software version differences*** between the systems: Which is the exact ***operating system*** version on each? Which is the exact ***ImageMagick*** version on each?

Comment: Looks like the `echo` statements are commented out. Is that intentional?

Comment: Hi KurtPfeifle, 


Local Machine
OS : Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
ImageMagick Version: 6.7.7-10


Live Server
OS : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)
ImageMagick: 6.7.8-9

Comment: Hi emcconville, I just commented out since it is for testing purpose.